# PhoneGap / Cordova + ChildBrowser Open In

Tags: ios, cordova

I have the latest ChildBrowser for iOS on phone gap 1.4.1 running.. it works perfectly except the share button in the top right  corner that opens the "Open In.." menu lists everything but Safari. (it lists iBooks, Kindle...)

I'm no ObjC developer, can anyone tell me how I can tweak that list? I want it to only show Safari as an option.